# How to change author (and) to (et) in \cite

Tags: citing

The question I think is prety clear. I'm citing Bob and Green, but I'm actually writing in french, so it doesn't make much sense to say 'selon ce que nous dit Bob and Green'. So I would like to change it to Bob et Green.

I went in the bib file, but when I change (and) to (et), the second author doesn't show up in the Tex file.

Any idea, and explanations ?

Comment: `and` is a keyword in a .bib file to separate multiple authors. If you use `biblatex`, this will be done automatically (I suppose you've loaded `babel` with option `french`).

Comment: yes I did. :(, what is bibltex, I<m using zotero,and the file is generated in.bib, should I choose another format ? How should I proceed

Comment: Not at all, `biblatex`  is a package for bibliographies which uses .bib files. It has many more possibilities than standard bibtex style files, especially when used as a front end to `biber` rather than `bibtex`, is easier to customise, and you can feed it  with utf8 encoded .bib files.

Comment: alright, thks. I'll check into that package later then

Answer (score 1):

Quite old, I know, but I use the IEEEtran template and fixed the 'and' string by replacing:

```
FUNCTION {bbl.and}{ "and" }
```

in the `STRING CONSTANTS` section of `IEEEtran.bst` file.

Hope this help someone.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You could use the code sample button to highlight your code. Editing the answer is possible everytime .