# Replace "e" by "and" [Jacobi, Schiele e Albertini 1988]

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, abntex2

I use `abntex2`.

I would like to replace the Portuguese "e"  in a `\cite` produced with the `abntex2-alf` style by the French "and"

> [Jacobi, Schiele e Albertini 1988]

Comment: I edited your question a bit to make it slightly easier to read, I hope I didn't change the intent of your question. If so, please correct me (the edit). With questions like this it always helps if you can include a small, yet complete example document that contains just enough code to reproduce the output you are currently seeing (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: Like with most `.bst` files, the words for "and", "and others", "edition" are hard-coded into the `abntex2-alf.bst`. If you want to change them, you need to copy the file, rename it (to say `abntex2-alf-fr.bst`) and edit the renamed copy. This is easier with `abntex2-alf.bst` than with other styles, because all strings are listed at the beginning `FUNCTION {bbl.<stringname>}`.

Comment: Related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/289245/35864

Comment: I did what you asked but unfortunately still the same thing. Thank you anyway

Comment: but I point out that I replaced the "e" and "and" by "et" in abntex2fr-alf. is this a modificatio move on my part?

Comment: Do not replace the `and`: The function name must still read `FUNCTION {bbl.and}` only change the string inside the function from `e` to `et`. Of course you will have to use `\bibliographystyle{abntex2-alf-fr}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{abntex2-alf}` in your document. You will also have to make sure that `\bibliographystyle{abntex2-alf-fr}` is in a place searched by BibTeX (usually the best option for a one-off is the same directory as your main `.tex` file).

Comment: Thank you very much, it's settled now

Comment: there remains the problem of the comma separating the author and the date:

Comment: [Gérard et Serge 2002]

Comment: I'm flabbergasted by someone trying to adapt the infamous `abnt` rules to French.